# QT Error: invalid conversion from QWidget* to QDialog*

Tags: c++, qt, qwidget, qdialog

please note: I am still new to c++, attempting to teach myself using qt creator.

I have the following error:

```
/home/cx/qt-projects/project-i/loginstatusdialog.cpp:11: error: invalid conversion from 'QWidget*' to 'QDialog*' [-fpermissive]
     ui->setupUi(parent);
                       ^
```

My header file:

```
#ifndef LOGINSTATUSDIALOG_H
#define LOGINSTATUSDIALOG_H

#include <QDialog>
#include <QtCore>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QtWidgets>
#include <thread>
#include "enums.h"

namespace Ui {
class LoginStatusDialog;
}

class LoginStatusDialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
//    explicit LoginStatusDialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    explicit LoginStatusDialog(QWidget *parent = 0, const QString &_login = NULL, const QString &_key = NULL);
    ~LoginStatusDialog();

private:

    Ui::LoginStatusDialog *ui;
    QString login, key;
};
#endif // LOGINSTATUSDIALOG_H
```

Implementation as follows

```
#include "loginstatusdialog.h"
#include "ui_loginstatusdialog.h"


QString DBServerIP = "x.x.x.x";
QString googleDNS = "8.8.8.8";


LoginStatusDialog::LoginStatusDialog(QWidget *parent, const QString &_login, const QString &_key) : QDialog(parent), ui(new Ui::LoginStatusDialog), login(_login), key(_key)
{
    ui->setupUi(parent);                   <<< -------- ISSUE LIES HERE ---------
    //some code here, etc.
    setResult(ENUM_SUCCESS);
}

LoginStatusDialog::~LoginStatusDialog()
{
    delete ui;
}
```

I have found a post with a mildly similar issue, but I do not follow the proposed solution,

Help with an explanation to the solution would be appreciated.

Comment: are you sure you don't you mean `ui->setupUi(this);`?

Comment: @Mike thanks for the response, the `ui->setupUi(parent)` was auto generated, I shall try it with `this`, does that make the `parent` parameter useless in this context?

Comment: No, it is auto generated as `ui->setupUi(this)`, try removing everything and adding a new form class again. The `parent` parameter is passed to the `QDialog(parent)` where it is handled, so, it is not useless.

Comment: I say the problem is in the `.ui` file. Or more exactly if you have created a QWidget in your `.ui` you can't make it a dialog in your `c++` code. Edit the `.ui` in designer.

Comment: @drescherjm I seem to have solved the issue, the QT designer autogenerated the `ui->setupUI(parent)` which was causing the issue (regardless of what Mike said), however Mike's solution is correct non the less.

Comment: @Mike could you possibly post an answer to the question, your suggest of using "this" worked. Also provide a small explanation as to why, thanks!

Comment: QtCreator's templates definitely to not autogenerate `ui->setupUi(parent)`, the `parent` is always just passed to the constructor of the base class.